# JIRA - Adding custom workflows

Tags: jira

We have the full Atlassian product range and I am looking at how to make best use of it

We are using Stash to manage our Git 1000+ repositories all of which contain tags pointing to their versions.

I need to be able to define how our software versions depend on each other

For example:

```
System_x.y.z in production consists of   
    group_of_components_a_x.y.x consists of
        component_a_x.y.z            
        component_b_x.y.z    
    ...    
System_x.y.z is release candidate_a consists of    
....    
System_x.y.z is in regression test    
...    
System_x.y.z is in performance test    
...    
System_x.y.z development is being tracked by Issue#    
...    
etc etc
```

I have been using ClearQuest to achieve this but would like to move to a pure Atlassian solution if it exists

I would also like to define a name for group_of_components so that I can attach owners to it as well as to components so we can use them elsewhere in the workflow.

- can notify them when versions change.
- In Issues so I can see when different teams are working in the same areas

I would also like to be able to use the System_x.y.z, group_of_components_x.y.z and component_a_x.y.z

- In Defects so I can see where the error was found (System_x.y.z, group_of_components_x.y.z)
- In Defects so I can see where the error was fixed (component_a_x.y.z)

Is any of this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Is any of this possible?

The short answer is yes. It's all possible.

Jira has the following hierarchy:

**Project**
../ **Epic**
../../ **Task**
../../../ **Sub-task**

**If you need to track version numbers** as part of a product roadmap you need to use Projects for that feature. There are probably other hacky ways to use labels or components to do something like this but you will spend endless hours extending these hacks throughout Jira. Not a fun exercise IMO.

> I need to be able to define how our software versions depend on each other

Dependencies can easily be added at the Epic/Task/Sub-task levels but I'm not aware of an easy way to do this at the version level. I'm only really aware of the Agile Cloud solutions. If you install this locally I'm fairly sure you could find a way to do this if it is truly needed.

> I would also like to define a name for group_of_components so that I can attach owners to it as well as to components so we can use them elsewhere in the workflow.

It's very easy to name all issue types and projects. Projects have an owner. All issue types can be assigned to any user (with access rights). Additionally you can add users to the "watch-list" of every issue.

> can notify them when versions change.

The watch-list will notify all watchers by email. Additionally you can set up workflows to reassign or marshal each record through a custom workflow.

> In Issues so I can see when different teams are working in the same areas

You can add users to teams in any combination (users can be on multiple teams) but I'm not sure I fully understand what "areas" means. You can search, filter and report on all issues by team(s) if that's what you mean.

> I would also like to be able to use the System_x.y.z, group_of_components_x.y.z and component_a_x.y.z
>
> > In Defects so I can see where the error was found (System_x.y.z, group_of_components_x.y.z)
> >     In Defects so I can see where the error was fixed (component_a_x.y.z)

Each bug you define:

1. can be organized into an Epic
2. can be associated to any number of tasks (Blocks task 1 or is blocked by task 2, etc.)
3. has one or many "affects versions" to track where the bug occurred
4. has one or many "fix versions" to track when the bug was fixed